# Check if one IEnumerable contains all elements of another IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

What is the fastest way to determine if one IEnumerable contains all the elements of another IEnumerable when comparing a field/property of each element in both collections?

---

```
public class Item
{
    public string Value;

    public Item(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

//example usage

Item[] List1 = {new Item("1"),new Item("a")};
Item[] List2 = {new Item("a"),new Item("b"),new Item("c"),new Item("1")};

bool Contains(IEnumerable<Item> list1, IEnumerable<Item>, list2)
{
    var list1Values = list1.Select(item => item.Value);
    var list2Values = list2.Select(item => item.Value);

    return //are ALL of list1Values in list2Values?
}

Contains(List1,List2) // should return true
Contains(List2,List1) // should return false
```

Comment: Which way round are your lists? Do you want to check if all items in list1 are in list 2 or that all items in list2 are in list 1?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

There is no "fast way" to do this unless you track and maintain some state that determines whether all values in one collection are contained in another. If you only have `IEnumerable<T>` to work against, I would use `Intersect`.

```
var allOfList1IsInList2 = list1.Intersect(list2).Count() == list1.Count();
```

The performance of this should be very reasonable, since `Intersect()` will enumerate over each list just once. Also, the second call to `Count()` will be optimal if the underlying type is an `ICollection<T>` rather than just an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I did some tests and this method seems to run faster than the others. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This does not work if there are duplicates in the list. For example comparing a char array of 441 and 414 returns 41 and thus the count fails.

Answer (score 124):

You could also use Except to remove from the first list all values that exist in the second list, and then check if all values have been removed:

```
var allOfList1IsInList2 = !list1.Except(list2).Any();
```

This method had the advantage of not requiring two calls to Count().

Comment: This is also good for finding out what is in List1 but not in List2;

Comment: This works in situations where list1 has duplicated values.  The accepted answer does not.

Comment: now how to do same with Contains? meaning list1.item[0].contains(list[0] and list[1] ...)

Answer (score 34):

C# 3.5+

Using [`Enumerable.All<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) to determine if all List2 items are contained in List1:

```
bool hasAll = list2Uris.All(itm2 => list1Uris.Contains(itm2));
```

This will also work when list1 contains even more than all the items of list2.

Comment: Ouch at performance implications of a `Contains()` call within an `All()` call.

Comment: Also you can moved it to group method: bool hasAll = list2Uris.All(list1Uris.Contains);

Comment: I case of IEnumerable<T> types this solution will provide n*m performance.

Comment: **Shorthand:** `bool hasAll = list2Uris.All(list1Uris.Contains);`

Comment: doesn't work for duplicates

Answer (score 3):

Kent's answer is fine and short, but the solution that he provides always requires iteration over the whole first collection. Here is the source code:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (first == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    if (second == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
    return Enumerable.IntersectIterator<TSource>(first, second, comparer);
}

private static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource source in second)
        set.Add(source);
    foreach (TSource source in first)
    {
        if (set.Remove(source))
            yield return source;
    }
}
```

That is not always required. So, here is my solution:

```
public static bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> subset, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    var hashSet = new HashSet<T>(subset, comparer);
    if (hashSet.Count == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        hashSet.Remove(item);
        if (hashSet.Count == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return hashSet.Count == 0;
}
```

Actually, you should think about using `ISet<T>` (`HashSet<T>`). It contains all required set methods. `IsSubsetOf` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

The solution marked as the answer would fail in the case of repetitions. If your IEnumerable only contains distinct values then it would pass.

The below answer is for 2 lists with repetitions:

```
        int aCount = a.Distinct().Count();
        int bCount = b.Distinct().Count();

        return aCount == bCount &&
               a.Intersect(b).Count() == aCount;
```

Comment: This is not a good solution since its removing all duplicates and not actually comparing them.

Answer (score 2):

You should use HashSet instead of Array.

Example:

```
List1.SetEquals(List2); //returns true if the collections contains exactly same elements no matter the order they appear in the collection
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516(v=vs.110).aspx)

The only HasSet limitation is that we can't get item by index like List nor get item by Key like Dictionaries. All you can do is enumerate them(for each, while, etc)

Comment: SetEquals doesn't answer the question; question is looking for "list1 IsSubsetOf list2" or "list2 IsSuperSetOf lost1"

Comment: @CaiusJard There is `IsSubsetOf` on `HashSet`s though (together with several other methods).

Answer (score 1):

the Linq operator SequenceEqual would work also (but is sensitive to the enumerable's items being in the same order)

```
return list1Uris.SequenceEqual(list2Uris);
```

Comment: SequenceEqual does not answer the question. Question is looking for some list1 elements present in equal or more list 2 elements. SequenceEqual can only return true if the two lists have the same number of values

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to convert your superset list to a `HashSet` and use the `IsSuperSet` method of `HashSet`.

```
bool Contains(IEnumerable<Item> list1, IEnumerable<Item>, list2)
{
    var list1Values = list1.Select(item => item.Value);
    var list2Values = list2.Select(item => item.Value).ToHashSet();

    return list2Values.IsSupersetOf(list1Values);
}
```