# C# Linq multi-word search

Tags: c#, linq, search

I have the following, where searchby is a string

```
var products = db.Products
   .Where(p => p.Category.Name == category 
          && p.Active == true 
          && (searchby == null || (searchby != null && p.Keywords.Contains(searchby))))
   .Include(p => p.Category)
   .OrderBy(p => p.Description)
   .ThenBy(p => p.Name);
```

and would like to change it to allow searchby to contain multiple words which would filter the results to records where Keywords contains all of the words in searchby.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if one IEnumerable contains all elements of another IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274541/check-if-one-ienumerable-contains-all-elements-of-another-ienumerable)

Comment: @Gusman: the duplicate doesn't help because OP needs a substring comparison (at least i thought `Keywords` is a `string`)

Comment: @TimSchmelter And what makes you think `Keywords` isn't an `IEnumerable`? As the OP hasn't specified the type of `Keywords` it can perfectly be a string array. Also, even if it's an string adding `p.Keywords.Split(' ').Contains(searchby)` it would work.

Comment: @Gusman: Since OP uses `Include` this seems to be Linq-To-Entities, that's what made me think that `KeyWords` is a string (he didn't use `.Include(p => p.Keywords)`). If it was another table the syntax would also be: `p.Keywords.Select(kw => kw.Name).Contains(searchby))`(presuming the `KeyWord` table would have a column `Name`)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok, fair enough,didn't saw the Include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another collection and either `Enumerable.All`(not sure if supported by your LINQ provider) or `!Enumerable.Any`:

```
List<string> searchby = ... (empty if there is no filter)
var products = db.Products
   .Where(p => p.Category.Name == category 
          && p.Active == true 
          && !searchby.Any(s => !p.Keywords.Contains(s)))
   .Include(p => p.Category)
   .OrderBy(p => p.Description)
   .ThenBy(p => p.Name);
```

If supported this is more readable:

```
&& searchby.All(s => p.Keywords.Contains(s)))
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer assumes, that searchby is either `null` or an Array.

Since contains only checks for 1 item, you need to find a way to check for all items within `searchby`. The `Enumerable.All`-Method comes to mind. Here is the relevant part:

```
searchby.All(searchItem => p.Keywords.Contains(searchItem))
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3274613/1392490)