# Trying to use Dynamic LINQ but don't know where to start?

Tags: c#, linq, blazor

I have a Blazor app that displays an event log that also has a multi-selectable drop-down that outputs a splitable string for type of "SourceContext" to filter by. I would like to dynamically build the "Where" clause like below, the code below obviously doesn't work but represents what I am trying to achieve.
I have tried Predicates and have read a few Dynamic LINQ sites to figure this out and I am completely confused at this point. Thank you for any help with this.

```
    string[] strAr = str.ToString().Split(",");
    string ctxFlt = string.Empty;
    for (int x = 1; x < strAr.Count(); x++)
    {
        if (x == 1)
        {
            ctxFlt += strAr[x].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ctxFlt += " and s.SourceContext ==  strAr[x].ToString();
        }
    }
    evLog = logdb.Logs.Where(s => s.SourceContext == $"{ctxFlt}").OrderByDescending(t => t.Timestamp).ToList();
```

Comment: Instinctively, I feel like you don't need Dynamic Linq or Predicate Builder for this.  Seems like a job for `Contains()`, or maybe `Except()`.    See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274541) for some clues.

Comment: I could not agree with you more. Contains is exactly what I would like to use. The issue is  when I try and concatenate the filter variables to look like "a, b, c" I get no records back. If I only use one variable it works. 

ctxFlt += strAr[x].ToString();
...
... where e.SourceContext.Contains(ctxFlt) ...

Comment: Contains is backwards - Try Where(s => strArs.Contains(s.SourceContext))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with Robert, Contains should be enough but you need a List (enum) not an Array for .Contains. Your Contains implementation is "String within String" ie foobar.Contains(foo) not a Linq Contains to build a SQL "WHERE field IN (x,y,z)"

```
var strAr = str.ToString().Split(",").ToArray().Distinct().ToList();
evLog = logdb.Logs.Where(s => strArs.Contains(s.SourceContext)).OrderByDescending(t => t.Timestamp).ToList();
```

But if you wanted a full blown dynamic query you would do something like below...

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

            string[] strAr = str.ToString().Split(",");
            Expression conditions = Expression.Constant(false);
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Log), "log");

            for (int i = 0; i < strAr.Count(); i++)
            {
                Expression condition = Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.Property(parameter, "SourceContext"),
                        Expression.Constant(strAr[i])
                        );

                conditions = Expression.OrElse(conditions, condition);
            }

            var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Log, Boolean>>(conditions, parameter);

            var q = evLog = logdb.Logs.Where(expression).OrderByDescending(t => t.Timestamp).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I had the original "Contains" backwards as stated. I did not know the array had to be evaluated first. The above "Contains" is the working answer. Thanks Robert and Mike!