# Entity Framework, entity .Contains multiple choices

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

The following code works for a single .Contains(tag) .

```cs
public async Task < List < CreateVideoWithTagNamesDTO >> FindVideosByTag(Tag tag) {
    var result = await _db.Where(p = >p.Tags.Contains(tag)).Select(item = >new CreateVideoWithTagNamesDTO {
        Description = item.Description,
        Title = item.Title,
        Url = item.Url,
        Tags = _mapper.Map < IList < CreateTagDTO >> (item.Tags)
    }).ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

How would I query Tags.Contains for multiple Tags? Let's say this function will take in array of Tags, Tag[] tags. How do I include .Contains to include all tags, so it would select videos which have each tag present?

Comment: What is `Tag` ? An enum? An entity with an ID ? What is `_db` ? It can't be a DbContext. There's no EF code in this question, unless `_db` is actually a DbSet<>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple tags you need to combine `Any` and `Contains` methods like below :

```
 public async Task<List<CreateVideoWithTagNamesDTO>> FindVideosByTag(ICollection<Tag> tags)
 {
    var result = await _db.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(tag=> tags.Contains(tag)))
       .Select( item => new CreateVideoWithTagNamesDTO
            {
                Description = item.Description,
                Title = item.Title,
                Url = item.Url,
                Tags = _mapper.Map<IList<CreateTagDTO>>(item.Tags)
            })
            .ToListAsync();


    return result;
 }
```

As @Panagiotis Kanavos pointed this may not work for complex objects EF will fail to convert this into SQL query but you can always fall back to this :

```
public async Task<List<CreateVideoWithTagNamesDTO>> FindVideosByTag(ICollection<Tag> tags)
 {
    var tagIds  = tags.Select(r=> r.Id).ToArray();
    var result = await _db.Where(p => p.Tags.Select(r=> r.Id).Any(tag=> tagIds.Contains(tag)))
       .Select( item => new CreateVideoWithTagNamesDTO
            {
                Description = item.Description,
                Title = item.Title,
                Url = item.Url,
                Tags = _mapper.Map<IList<CreateTagDTO>>(item.Tags)
            })
            .ToListAsync();


    return result;
 }
```

**Edit** As the question evolves if you want Videos that contains all the tags in the provided list you should change `Any` with `All`

```
public async Task<List<CreateVideoWithTagNamesDTO>> FindVideosByTag(ICollection<Tag> tags)
 {
    var tagIds  = tags.Select(r=> r.Id).ToArray();
    var result = await _db.Where(p => p.Tags.Select(r=> r.Id).All(tag=> tagIds.Contains(tag)))
       .Select( item => new CreateVideoWithTagNamesDTO
            {
                Description = item.Description,
                Title = item.Title,
                Url = item.Url,
                Tags = _mapper.Map<IList<CreateTagDTO>>(item.Tags)
            })
            .ToListAsync();


    return result;
 }
```

Comment: This won't work if `Tag` is anything but an enum. If it is, `Contains` would also work. Unless EF is smart enough to use only the PK from `Tag` in the SQL query - in which case `Contains` would also work.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for pointing that out. I will add another example.

Comment: This will find all videos that contain any tag in tags list. How can I make it so that video should contain ALL tags in tagslist, not just any.

I.e 
var result = await _db.Where(p => p.Tags.Contains(tags[0]) && p.Tags.Contains(tags[1]))
something like that

Comment: @Jeekim you can achieve that changing `Any` with `All`

Comment: Its not working properly for me. It makes sense however somethings wrong. I will mark this as answer and make new question with more detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intersect function in list to get matched items and use that
u can refer to below question
[Check if one IEnumerable contains all elements of another IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274541/check-if-one-ienumerable-contains-all-elements-of-another-ienumerable)