# FluentAssertions: Test if an Enumerable contains "subset" of itself

Tags: c#, testing, fluent-assertions

I'm looking for the elegant expression to test if an enumerable contains a 'subset' of itself.

Lets me illustrate with a sample:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    // Arrange
    var expected = new[]
    {
        new {F1 = 1, F2 = "1" },
        new {F1 = 2, F2 = "2" },
    };

    // Act
    var actual = new[]
    {
        new {F1 = 1, F2 = "1", F3 = true },
        new {F1 = 2, F2 = "2", F3 = true },
        new {F1 = 3, F2 = "3", F3 = true },
    };

    // Assert
    actual
        .Should()
        .LookingForFluentAssertionsExpression( //<-- I'm looking for this part
            expected, 
            options => options.SomeOptions(),
            because: "expected is a 'subset' of actual" 
        );
}
```

I have tried unsuccessfully with [Object graph comparison](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/):

```cs
    // Assert
    actual
        .Should()
        .BeEquivalentTo(expected, o => o.ExcludingMissingMembers());
```

> Expected actual to be a collection with 2 item(s), but {{ F1 = 1, F2 = 1, F3 = True }, { F1 = 2, F2 = 2, F3 = True }, { F1 = 3, F2 = 3, F3 = True }}"
>
> "contains 1 item(s) more than"
>
> "{{ F1 = 1, F2 = 1 }, { F1 = 2, F2 = 2 }}.

Obviously, I can do:

```cs
    // Assert
    actual
        .Where(a => expected.Any(e=>e.F1 == a.F1 && e.F2 == a.F2))
        .Should()
        .BeEquivalentTo(expected, o => o.ExcludingMissingMembers());
```

but looks a bit dirty.

Another option is:

```cs
    // Assert
    expected
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(expectedItem =>
            actual
                .Should()
                .ContainEquivalentOf(
                    expectation: expectedItem, 
                    config: o => o.ExcludingMissingMembers())
        );

    // Or the same without Linq: 
    //
    //foreach (var expectedItem in expected)
    //{
    //    actual
    //        .Should()
    //        .ContainEquivalentOf(
    //            expectation: expectedItem,
    //            config: o => o.ExcludingMissingMembers());
    //}
```

but is not readable at all.

Comment: The question is a bit misleading this is what would be the answer if you actually wanted to test the subset : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274541/check-if-one-ienumerable-contains-all-elements-of-another-ienumerable. Well I see a problem with your code you use anonymous objects which when it comes to equality you check the ref of the object. I would suggest using an actual object and override the Equals function.

Comment: Hi @panoskarajohn, thanks about your comment. This is just a "minimal reproducible sample". In my scenario, override Equals is not a viable. Remember that FluentAssertions has methods to test graphs of objects (<- I just updated my question to talk about Object graph comparison)

Comment: Put your `actual` into a `HashSet<>`. Afterwards you can call `actualHashSet.IsSupersetOf(expected)`. Be aware, that depending on the type you have to provide an `IEqualityComparer<T>` into the ctor of the hashset, but anonymous types have value semantics, so you shouldn't need it in your example. Also you could do the reverse and call `expectedHashSet.IsSubsetOf(actual)`, depending on your needs.

Comment: @Oliver, thanks a lot about your suggestion, can you elaborate it in an answer or in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) with a bit of code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two calls of `ContainEquivalentOf` where you pass an item from the `expected` collection.

e.g.

```
using (new AssertionScope())
{
  actual.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(expected[0]);
  actual.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(expected[1]);
}
```

And you don't need `ExcludingMissingMembers`. FA will only expect the properties you defined on your expectation.

Comment: Are you so kind to elaborate with a bit of code, please?

Comment: Looks fine for few items. Thanks

Comment: What do you think about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75296827/842935

Comment: Looks a bit too complicated for me. A simple loop would have worked as well. You could even wrap that loop in an `AssertionScope` like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I coded it using a [ClassData](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/). I don't know if this is the best solution, I post it here with the other answers. Feel free to criticize this answer. We are here to learn.

```cs
public class CalculatorTestData : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] { new { F1 = 1, F2 = "1" }, "reason 1" };
        yield return new object[] { new { F1 = 2, F2 = "2" }, "reason 2" };
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(CalculatorTestData))]
public void Test2(object expected, string because)
{
    // Arrange

    // Act
    var actual = new[]
    {
        new {F1 = 1, F2 = "1", F3 = true },
        new {F1 = 2, F2 = "2", F3 = true },
        new {F1 = 3, F2 = "3", F3 = true },
    };

    // Assert
    actual
        .Should()
        .ContainEquivalentOf(
            expectation: expected,
            because: because);
}
```